# unusual jekyll if statement

Tags: ruby, jekyll

I am trying to filter posts using this `if` statement.

When I print `page.label` & `post.tags` they gets correctly printed.
but when I compares them, it doesn't work.

```
Line 1      {{ page.label }}  //outputs music
Line 2      {{ post.tags }}   //outputs music
Line 3       {% if post.tags == page.label %}
Line 4        <h2>hello</h2>  //nothing happens here
Line 5       {% endif %}
```

On the other hand if i replace `==` with `!=` in Line `3` then `hello` gets printed.
I really don't understand these baseless outputs

Please help

**EDIT**

This is my front matter for posts

```
---
layout:     post
title:      Audio Recording
date:       2017-04-09 06:30:45
summary:   
tags: music
comments: true
---
```

Comment: `tags` looks like an array and `label` looks like a string. How do you expect them to be equal?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev okay...so tags is an array type by default in jekyll?

Comment: Jekyll doesn't assume anything. What do you pass as `post.tags`?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I am passing post.tags value from posts jekyll font matter. Please see the edit in question

Comment: Yah, that `tags` is an array. Also, it's "front matter", not "font matter".

Comment: yeahh sorry typo....So it is by default an array always?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Or can I make post.tags a string as well?

Comment: Yep, it's always an array.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Thanks